# Show highest and lowest price in a view from a node reference

Tags: views, 6, nodes

I have a content type called **Cars**, and a content type called **Prices**.  They are node referenced.  The **Prices** content type has a decimal cck field for the price called **field_price**.    So you can create a new **Prices** node that will have the price for the car.  There are multiple **Prices** nodes for each **Car** node.  In views, how would I be able to show the lowest and highest prices for the car.  For instance, it would say, **Prices for this car range from $10,568 to $18,259**.

Comment: Why do you create the price as a content type instead of using a CCK field that allows multiple values to hold the price?

Comment: For price comparison shopping.  It is actually a little more complicated than I explained.  Each Price node for a certain car is put into a view and attached to a car node.  It has the sellers name, the price, and the sellers link to that car.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more fancy-pants way to do this, but I would take the view template, extract the car type, and do a manual MIN() MAX() query to fetch these values.

Comment: Can I stick the MIN() MAX() query right in a views-field.tpl?

Comment: You'd want it on the page template, not the field, right? I mean, the answer is yes, put it in the appropriate template. Or rather, write the function in a module somewhere and call it in the template.

Comment: But if this is a view, it needs to go in a field tpl to be added to the view.  Printing it in the page tpl would just print it arbitrarily on the page.  Am I correct?

Comment: It really depends on how your view is structured. If the view is a list of the members of one type of automobile, then you wouldn't want a count on each field. If the view is a list of types, you /would/ want the count on each field. Make sense? I'd just put it generally: add the code to the appropriate tpl ;)